# OpenGL GLX extension not supported

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, glut, xlib, glx

I had installed OpenGL and freeglut in Ubuntu 10.04 and it worked fine in 10.04 and 10.10. But after I upgraded to 11.04, the applications I've developed using OpenGL is not running properly. They're compiling without errors, but when I try to execute them, I get there errors:

For GLUT:

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
freeglut (./a.out): OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display ':0.0'
```

For just OpenGL:

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
main: X server has no OpenGL GLX extension
```

A few things I tried:

> ```
> $glxgears
> Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
> Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
>
>
> $glxinfo
> name of display: :0.0
> Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
> Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
> Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
> Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
> Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
> Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
>
> Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
> Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
> Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
> Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
> Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
> Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
> Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
> ```

Edit:
It is unlikely that this is because I don't have the graphics drivers as all I have is on board graphics.

This is my system graphics information from sysinfo

> ```
> $sysinfo
> GRAPHIC CARD
>       VGA controller
>     Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
>     Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff50
> ```

Edit 2:
And it seems I have a driver installed for that.

> ```
> $lshw -C display
>   *-display:0             
>        description: VGA compatible controller
>        product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
>        vendor: Intel Corporation
>        physical id: 2
>        bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
>        version: 07
>        width: 64 bits
>        clock: 33MHz
>        capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
>        configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
>        resources: irq:44 memory:f4000000-f43fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:1800(size=8)
> ```

Look at "configuration: driver="

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those messages simply tell you, that your graphics drivers are not installed properly. GLX is the extension of the X11 protocol for making OpenGL work in X11 windows. There are 3 parts to a GLX enabled system:

- A kernel module, doing the talking to the GPU (this is either the Linux-Kernel DRM, or fglrx of ATI/AMD or nvidia from NVidia).
- A X server GLX extension module, talking to the kernel module, converting OpenGL operations into the GPU specifric commands.
- The client side libGL.so which also implements the GLX protocol. There's the DRI2 based libGL of Mesa, and the proprietary libGL.so of either ATI/AMD or NVidia.

For OpenGL to work properly those three components must be properly installed and loaded to work in harmony. If that's not the case you won't be able to use OpenGL (or only use a software rasterizer, which is not properly installed either on your system).

Comment: I just have on board graphics. No graphics card.

Comment: @SparrowG: That makes no difference. You need a driver for that as well.

Comment: after some research, it seems a graphics driver is installed already. I'm updating the question with that as well.

Comment: @SparrowG: lshw only tells you, which driver to install, not if it is installed. In your case `apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx` and restarting X should do the trick.

Comment: didn't work for me :( Anyway thanks for identifying the problem

Comment: How to probe which of the 3 is the bad one?

Comment: @Ekevoo: We can rule out the last one `libgl1-mesa-glx` as it is this, that's detecting a problem in the first place (it's implementing the GLX client side, which informs you, that it's missing GLX capabilities on the server). Have a look at the `/var/log/Xorg.<n>.log` files. The X server is telling you there what's missing. Ignore the warnings (WW), as there will always be some of them, look for errors (EE).

Answer (score 6):

You could need Bumblebee. But this is supported only for 12.04 and from 13.10 up.
Oficial instructions here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

You need to open your terminal and enter the commands below.

If on 12.04.3, replace **linux-headers-generic** with **linux-headers-generic-lts-raring**.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable`

Enable the Universe and Multiverse repositories (for bumblebee and nvidia packages respectively).

`sudo apt-get update`

Install Bumblebee using the default proprietary nvidia driver:

`sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic`

Reboot

All should be ok now.

Comment: Worked for me on an Acer C710 running Chrubuntu running 12.04.3 LTS.

Comment: I had problems running cura (it was hanging on rendering) on xubuntu 15.10 and by some unbelievable miracle, this fixed it. Really. Miracle. Nothing like this ever gets fixed.