# LibGDX UI Setup Desktop Project error

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, installation, libgdx

i'm using eclipse kepler 4.3, I've installed the android sdk plugin, and installed everything required with the sdk manager, and I've also installed the Google Web Toolkit plugin as required. I'm on ubuntu (linux) using openjdk-6. I've created my projects with the libgdx ui project creator thing, and I used nightly build with both of the third party programs. I imported them into eclipse fixed the android and html 5 errors, but I still have one error on my desktop project. The constructor LwjglApplication(Main, LwjglApplicationConfiguration) is undefined on line 14 of this class : http://pastie.org/8398405
I've tried googling, and stack overflow, but the only thing I found was the same error with the solution : "I installed GWT and it fixed the previous 2 errors", however i've already installed gwt, unless i'm being a derp and there are further setup instructions passed going to the install software thing, typing in the link installing it, and restarting.
I would really appreciate any help, thanks guys :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your core class (the main class in your core project) is called Main,just like the one in the Desktop project. So, like that, the desktop one is sending an instance of itself:

this:

```
new LwjglApplication(new yourpackage.Main(), cfg);
```

or changing the name of that class will solve your problem.

Comment: Well that fixed the error, but when I tried running this I get : Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0". Any Idea?

Comment: Your graphics drivers are not installed properly http://stackoverflow.com/a/8545496/1895303