# LibGDX XLib Extension: "GLX" Error

Tags: java, 2d, libgdx, xlib, glx

Well I'm trying to setup libgdx. I used the setup-ui and installed everything on eclipse, but I get this error when I try to run my desktop project : http://pastie.org/8399448
I'm running ubuntu, and I think this might have something to do with why my android emulator won't work in eclipse, but I don't really need it because i'm not planning to make it into an android app. Thanks for taking time to read this/help me. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing some basic OpenGL setup on your system.  Its not Libgdx-specific.  For example does `glxgears` run?

See [OpenGL GLX extension not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545291/opengl-glx-extension-not-supported).

The answer is probably going to be very to Ubuntu and the video card your machine is using.  You might have more luck at [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: Well it didn't run, because I didn't have mesa-utils installed, so I installed them, and then ran glxgears and this is what I got: Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual

Comment: Yeah, its not a Libgdx or Java problem.  It is your X11 configuration that needs an extension loaded to support OpenGL on your video hardware.  Search the Ubuntu forums...