# How to use Xdummy to get GLX support on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, xvfb, glx

I am trying to use OpenAI `gym` through Jupyter on AWS (running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS). When I try and use the `env.render()` function I get an error. The problem is that `env.render()` uses `pyglet`, but when trying to import it I get the following error: `GLXInfoException: pyglet requires an X server with GLX`.

I have tried

- using `xvfb`, but from what I can see it doesn't support GLX.
- using `bumblebee`, but since AWS is a VM I can't install it.

In `/var/log/Xorg.<n>.log` get the following errors:

```
...
[   742.810] (EE) cirrus: The PCI device 0xb8 at 00@00:02:0 has a kernel module claiming it.
[   742.810] (EE) cirrus: This driver cannot operate until it has been unloaded.
...
[   742.854] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
...
```

---

A solution using `Docker` is posted [here](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/247). I was not able to adapt this to run directly on an AMI, which I would like.

A similar problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545291/opengl-glx-extension-not-supported), but I don't know how to adapt this to my case.